# ScrollView in xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

I use ScrollView in my layout like this :

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- my rest xml code-->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

then my layout preview show like this :

[image: this is screenshot on my layout preview]

why layout look like this?!

Comment: Copy your fill XML

Comment: It is showing  because of you take ScrollView As your root view. Try to put root view other than scroll view.

Comment: Mention the output which you want

Comment: but i suppose there is an extra vertical View on my layout , so i but ScrollView the root , so it's wrong to be root??

Comment: @YazanKhateeb Post your full *Layout* with rest of the *code*.

Comment: how can i post my full code?

Comment: @YazanKhateeb check my answer. hope it help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just because you used `ScrollView` as Root View.

Change the Root View as your need(LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/FrameLayout) and add ScrollView as Child layout under Root View.

For e.g.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- your rest xml code-->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: It's not wrong but ScrollView just a View, not Layout.

Comment: but it's extends from GroupView Class as LinearLayout !!

Comment: Are you sure that we cannot use scroll view as a root view? It supposed to be written on the documentations but it is not? I am getting error about scroll view can only have one child even tough it has only one, I need to understand if this is the reason. Thanks in advance

Comment: We can use scrollview as rootview. And yes scrollview has only one child, we can use our layout view inside the childview. Like Scrollview -> LinearLayout(child) -> Multiview views or layout.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your issue is the view is shrinked though you set the child layout height as `match_parent`. to make it proper. you have add `fillViewport` to true.

Ex :

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport=true
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        //child 
</ScrollView>
```

read the documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
// you can use the scrollview like below code
//where your scroll view must conatin a root view contain all child vies

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".uiApplication.hmactivties">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgsecond"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  </RelativeLayout>
```